# iPhone:How to store apostrophe(') sign in sqlite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

In UITextView I write my text and on the button click this text store in database but when I use apostrophe(') sign in my text. My query shows me error near apostrophe sign then please tell me how to insert apostrophe sign in sqlit database.

thanx in advance...

Comment: Use a placeholder and a [bound value](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to double the apostrophe sign in your text (i.e. `''` instead of `'`).

Answer (score 3):

This may be of some help as well when you want to replace a single quote with two double quotes.

Method:

```
 - (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Example:

```
[someString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should double the apostrophe ' to be double ''

Answer (score 1):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes
>   ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded **by putting two
>   single quotes in a row** - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the
>   backslash character are not supported because they are not standard
>   SQL.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html